# Browser automate tasks

Tags: jquery, python, google-chrome

So I am watching some videos on a webpage where there is a playlist. The problem with the playlist is that it doesnt "auto-play". SO everytime one video ends I have to manually go to the playlist and click on the "next" link.

Is there any way to automate this? SOmething like:

```
1.go to this page
2.select the active item in the list(which contains the video duration)
3.extract the video duration from the active item and let the video play
4.After video duration, ex: 4min, click on the next element of the list and let it play for the video duration...
...
```

I am confortable with python and jquery. using the google chrome console is possible to achive this? Or any external script that I can run? I have also seen Imacros but it records specific itens, and I need something dynamic/procedual. Like find the next element of the active selected item.

Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) to automate a variety of browsers.

There are [Python bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) for Selenium in PyPI - you can see some examples of the code on the linked page, for example:

- open a new Firefox browser
- load the Yahoo homepage
- search for "seleniumhq"
- close the browser

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
assert 'Yahoo!' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input DNA. Just a quick question:
Is it possible to tell the code to hold for 4min(video duration) and then click on the next link? Thanks

Comment: You can just use `time.sleep()`. See also http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html for ways to wait for certain conditions to occur.